# python pyinstaller no library called "cairo" was found

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, cairo, pycairo

While compiling an app dependent on `matplotlib` and `pyside2` with `pyinstaller` I get these errors

**Environment**

```
 PyInstaller: 3.5
 Python: 3.7.5
 Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
```

**Errors**

```
    31256 INFO:   Matplotlib backend GTK3Agg: ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File c:\users\digikwondo\pycharmprojects\guitest\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_cairo.py, line 14, in <module>
    import cairo
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cairo

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
    File "c:\users\digikwondo\pycharmprojects\guitest\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_gtk3agg.py, line 4, in <module>
    from . import backend_agg, backend_cairo, backend_gtk3
    File "c:\users\digikwondo\pycharmprojects\guitest\venv\lib\site- 
    packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_cairo.py", line 20, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
    File "c:\users\digikwondo\pycharmprojects\guitest\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    ('libcairo.so', 'libcairo.2.dylib', 'libcairo-2.dll'))
    File "c:\users\digikwondo\pycharmprojects\guitest\venv\lib\site-packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
    OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
    no library called "libcairo-2" was found
    cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e
    cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
    cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0x7e
```

my import statements

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QWidget, QLineEdit, QTextBrowser, QListWidget, QFileDialog, QTabWidget, QGridLayout) 
from PySide2.QtCore import (Slot, QRect, QFile, QTextStream)
from PySide2.QtGui import (QIcon, QFont)
from zipfile import (ZipFile)
from pandas.io.common import EmptyDataError
import glob
import sys
import os
import time
import pandas
import logging
import webbrowser
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator as mxl
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
```

pip packages installed

```
altgraph          0.16.1
arrow             0.15.4
attrs             19.3.0
cairocffi         1.1.0
certifi           2019.9.11
cffi              1.13.2
chardet           3.0.4
Click             7.0
cycler            0.10.0
future            0.18.2
joblib            0.14.0
kiwisolver        1.1.0
llvmlite          0.30.0
matplotlib        3.1.1
Nuitka            0.6.5
numba             0.45.1
numpy             1.17.4
packaging         19.1
pandas            0.25.1
pefile            2019.4.18
pip               19.0.3
pip-review        1.0
pip-tools         4.1.0
pycparser         2.19
PyInstaller       3.5
pyparsing         2.4.2
pypiwin32         223
PyQt5             5.13.0
PyQt5-sip         4.19.19
pyqt5-tools       5.13.0.1.5
PySide2           5.13.1
python-dateutil   2.8.1
python-dotenv     0.10.3
pytz              2019.2
pywin32           225
pywin32-ctypes    0.2.0
scikit-learn      0.21.3
scipy             1.3.1
setuptools        41.2.0
setuptools-freeze 0.0.1
shiboken2         5.13.1
sip               4.19.8
six               1.13.0
tornado           6.0.3
umap              0.1.1
umap-learn        0.3.10
```

i am not sure what the implications are as pyinstaller finishes and my app runs without issues. 
would appreciate some help understanding these errors and how to resolve them

Comment: @dikiwondo: as a token of appreciation could you please mark the answer as accepted? (gray tick mark besides the question).

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, on top of `cairocffi` you need to install Gtk++ from [here](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer) and ensure the library `libcairo-2.dll` is available on the system `PATH`. (Keeping the "Set up PATH environment variable" checkbox checked in the installer seems to do the trick.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, installing gtk++ resolved issues . 

is there a way to package required files with pyinstaller so there is no need to install gtk ? goal is making my app portable (just one stand alone  exe)

Comment: You would need to install all of the dependencies (Gtk++) along with your application. It does not fit the idea of one portable executable.

Comment: Just to add on, install with the default options it automatically adds it to the path. And also make sure to close and reopen your ide for it to work.