# How can you render an SVG to a png in a specific size (python)

Tags: python-3.x, svg

I am Working on a small Image comparing script where the reference images are generated as SVGs and the compare images are PNGs.
I can transform the SVG files to PNG (using svglib and renderpm) but can´t specify the size I want them to be generated as(renderscale seems to cut of a part of the picture), but I need to get them to the same size for the compare functions and resizing the pngs nullifyes the whole purpose of vector graphics in itself. Any Ideas?

Regards a python noob

Comment: Did you try `cairosvg` https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135174/18667225 ?

Comment: @Markus  i have tried cairosvg, but I cant manage to get it working. it alswaysthows exceptions  for "missing librarys" https://prnt.sc/ZmNdtpohRGFw

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60935922/18667225 ?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. The Problem I am having now is that the output png is rendered in different colors (the white imge Background is converted to gray) which is counterproductive as I am working with error measuring. Edit: background_color="white" solves ist.

Comment: Update question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73607300/cairosvg-renders-pngs-wierdly-in-python

Comment: I got `svglib` to work with `pymupdf` [on my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74164750/1506569) where the output size can be influenced by the `dpi` parameter. And it doesn't require any external libs, in case someone stumbles across this post as I did.